# Blue border appearing around NSScrollView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nsoutlineview, nsscrollview

I'm sure this is normal and I'm just misunderstanding something, but since making one of my `NSScrollView`s slightly inset from the bottom of the window (as opposed to taking the full height), a blue border has appeared around it.

I've set `NSNoBorder` on the scroll view, so this must be something else.

```
[scrollView setBorderType:NSNoBorder];
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.  I'd like the border to go away as it spoils the look of the app and just looks broken.

I assume it's the scroll view.  The view inside it as an `NSOutlineView`, so maybe it's something on that?

[image: Blue border]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's the focus ring.   It shows which view is going to get the keystrokes if the user types anything.  If you suppress it, then your app will not be in compliance with the UI guidelines.

Comment: Thanks.  I have a layout a lot like Xcode.  In a split view, at the left of my app, there's a directory tree.  How come this blue box does not appear in Xcode's outline view/scroll view?

Comment: Found it, thanks very much. -setFocusRingType: can be set to none.