# Remove border from NSScrollView/NSCollectionView

Tags: cocoa, nsscrollview, nscollectionview

As you can see in the screenshot below, the `NSCollectionView` I used has some kind of border (the thin gray lines) I want to get rid of. Can somebody tell me how to achieve this? I already tried subclassing the NSCollectionView and tried to overwrite it in the `drawRect:` by using `[[super layer] setBorderWidth:0.0f];` but this did not work.

[image]

Searching on Google, SO and the Apple Documentation did not help either. So did anyone achieved this already or knows where I can find an example of how to do it?

Thanks in advance,
Björn

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am having the same problem except my border is blue. It's along the left and top only.

Comment: I did not work on the project for a few months but with the latst version of Xcode you can disable the border in Interface Builder. Just select the Scroll View and then disable the border like in this screenshot http://cl.ly/image/3W232g2P0e0f. After you've done that it should disappear. I was either blind last year or they simply changed it in the current Xcode version :-)

Comment: I found that my problem was actually a dup of this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366796/blue-border-appearing-around-nsscrollview?rq=1).

Answer (score 8):

The collectionView is nested in a NSScrollView, which has a borderType property.
You can get rid of the border by simply setting its border type to NSNoBorder.

```
self.collectionView.enclosingScrollView.borderType = NSNoBorder;
```

Comment: Do you know how to hide the scroll bar altogether?

Comment: @Supertecnoboff Have you found a way to hide the scroll bar, please?

Answer (score 2):

## From story board:

1. Select the scroll view from story board

[image]

2. Then choose no boarder from Attributes Inspector

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 3 :-

```
collectionView.enclosingScrollView?.borderType = .noBorder
```